# Maven: package org.junit does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm new to Maven, so excuse me if this is so elemental. I have searched about this problem, and everyone seems to solve it removing the  tag from the pom.xml file.

I do not have that tag there:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>GraphApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>GraphApp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <name>MyApp</name>
  <description>MyApp</description>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I have converted an existing project with Eclipse, so the problem may come from that.

Also, I have read that the default schema for Maven is storing the code at some default folders, while I'm using `src/com/romanrdgz/core/myapp` and `/test/com/romanrdgz/test/core`. That could also be the origin of the problem.

I am seeing this error:

```
Maven: package org.junit does not exist
```

What do I need to change?

EDIT: Ok, I have included JUnit4 as dependency, and I have also changed my file folders to be like this:
[image]

Still, when I go to console and execute `mvn test` or `mvn compile`, I get the following output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building GraphApp 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ GraphApp -
--
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\rrrp\workspace\GraphApp\src\
main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ GraphApp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.515 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-15T08:15:06+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried erasing bin and target folders, but still the same. Looks like it does not find the classes nor the tests.

Any help?

Comment: Please post the actual stacktrace.

Comment: Add the junit dependency to the pom

Comment: @Reimeus  tried, but eclipse shows it as an error. Where into the pom should I add it?

Comment: ok have posted answer

Comment: Why are you changing the default locations `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` ? Good reason for it? I have doubts about that.

Comment: @khmarbaise It was just my first time with Maven, I am not used to that exact structure

Comment: So go back to the defaults and don't change them if you don't have quite good reason to do so.

Comment: @khmarbaise After changing it, still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the junit dependency to the pom file in a dependencies section

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

.....
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Ok, that totally works. i was misplacing it. Quick question: If i launch all tests from console with "mvn test", I am getting warning "using platgorm encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources" and info "skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\myuser\workspace\MyApp\src\test\resources". My tests are not there, but in \MyApp\test. How to change the pom?

Comment: But, do I have to stick to the default Maven folder structure? Which one is that? Or do I just have to create an empty test\resources folder?

Comment: You dont have to but I would - it's easier

Comment: This should have the `<scope>test</scope>` tag to avoid building the tests into the final production build.